# Twilio Taskrouter Task Stuck on 'Wrapping'

Tags: php, twilio

I'm creating an application using Taskrouter. For the most part everything works fine except one thing, when the call is hung up a task is created with status 'wrapping' and it never ends (I give up on waiting after 20-30 minutes). I suspect since the timeout value for the task is 1 day it would end then but that's not very useful. The worker, even though they show as available, cannot take calls because they are still assigned to this wrap-up task.

When the task is assigned and a call is initially dequeued and routed to the worker, the postWorkActivitySid is used to update the worker's activity back to Idle once the call ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The "wrapping up" task is actually just a phase that all tasks can go through and in this case isn't a new task, but the existing one in a new state. It gives the worker time to finish anything up that they need to do in the aftermath of a call without them receiving a new call. See [the last two stages of this example workflow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter#example-taskrouter-application-flow).

In order to complete the task and free up the worker to receive new calls you need to complete the task.

If you are using the TaskRouter JS you can [complete the task with a call to `worker.completeTask`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#completetask).

If you are just using the REST API then you can complete the task by [setting the `AssignmentStatus` of the task to `completed`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/tasks#action-update).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes, this helps very much. I was going off an example and it didn't contain code to update the task, which is what threw me off. I'll be adding the functionality to my version! Thank you Phil :)

Comment: Fantastic, glad to have helped!